# How to create instance of service bound HttpClient?

Tags: c#, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.0

I have Identity Server 4 hosted in my service. It exposes various endpoints, and I would like to access `token` endpoint from same service.
It does not expose any interface, so I just could inject it as a dependency, hence I have to make an http request.

Now I set urls of  `HttpClient` like this:

```
var req = _contextAcessor.HttpContext.Request;
var baseAddr = $"{req.Scheme}://{req.Host}";
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddr);

var addr = _urlHelperProvider.GetUrlHelper().Content("~/connect/token");
```

I don't like it because here `localhost` is not even used. But service may be bound to different port on localhost, and I have no idea how to get the list of urls passed to [`UseUrls`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.hostingabstractionswebhostbuilderextensions.useurls?view=aspnetcore-2.2) method.

Ideally, I'd like to have instance of the client bound to my service similar how it works with [`WebApplicationFactory.CreateClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.testing.webapplicationfactory-1.createclient?view=aspnetcore-2.2) method.

Comment: Having trouble parsing this -- are you asking how to register a configuration-bound HttpClient in a DI container?

Comment: Nope, how do I get http client which has BaseAddress pointing to my service? Or http client with the handler which does not even use network, but memory only.

Comment: If you are in the same process as Identity Server 4 have you explored using `IdentityServerTools` for internally generating tokens?  See http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/tools.html

Comment: @Richard yes, same process. I looked at tools, and they are just for issuing tokens, however endpoint does more. And it is not only about IS4, but everything else which is hosted within same process and could be accessed in-memory.

Comment: I'm not sure I've got what you really need, but probably that's something like 
`public static string GetIdentityServerBaseUrl(this HttpContext context)` from `IdentityServer4.Extensions` namespace. as you can see, that's an extension method for HttpContext, so it can be called from any controller the following way: `HttpContext.GetIdentityServerBaseUrl()`

Answer (score 0):

Was hoping to find an answer here but got it working eventually
So hopefully this might help someone

when you create your client, it might is often helpful to set the host with https
It should be equal to whatever host you have by default when running your application locally

```
_factory = new WebApplicationFactory<Startup>().WithWebHostBuilder(BuildHost);
        Client = _factory.CreateClient(new WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions()
        {
            BaseAddress = new System.Uri("https://localhost:5031")
        });
```

Then your request is simply:

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "grant_type", "client_credentials" },
            { "scope", "SomeScope" }, 
            { "client_id", "YourClientId" }, { "client_secret", "yoursecret" } };


        var encodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);

        var response = await Client.PostAsync("/connect/token", encodedContent);
```

Have tested it locally and it works 
Please let me know if you still have any issues with your setup,
should be able to help